# Calculating rank on an aggregate column in a Hibernate SQLProjection

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria, aggregation, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to write a query to calculate a rank column based upon an aggregate column. The query is an SQLProjection as part of a Hibernate Criteria query. **Here is what I have tried:**

```
String sqlProjection = 
    "(select count(*) from IPTStatistic stat2 where 
               max(s.powerRestarts) > max({alias}.powerRestarts)) as rank)";

ProjectionList list = Projections.projectionList();

list.add(Projections.sqlProjection(sqlRankQuery, new String[]{"rank"}, new Type[]{new IntegerType()})));
list.add(Property.forName("managedObjectName").group());
list.add(Projections.max("powerRestarts").as("maxRestarts"));

Criteria crit = hibernateSessionHelper.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(IPTStatistic.class);
crit.setProjection(projection);

crit.list();
```

When I use a non-aggregate column in the SQL projection, the subselect works and I get the expected results, it is only once I introduce the `max()` that the error occurs.

This throws a fairly non-specific `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException` with message "`Could not execute query`".

The log shows:

```
WARN   logExceptions, SQL Error: -458, SQLState: S1000
ERROR  logExceptions, java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I can't pinpoint the problem in the query myself from the above error messages, can anyone give me some pointers on how to correct my query?

---

**UPDATE:**

I am now using the following sqlProjection as per axtavt's answer below:

```
String sqlProjection = "(select count(*) from " +
    "(select name from IPTStatistic s group by s.name " + 
    "    having max(s.powerRestarts) > max({alias}.powerRestarts)) " +
    "as r) as rank"
```

The SQL generated by Hibernate is:

```
select (select count(*) from (select iptManagedObjectName from IPTStatistic s group by s.iptManagedObjectName having max(s.powerRestarts) > max(this_.powerRestarts)) as r) as rank, this_.iptManagedObjectName as y1_, from IPTStatistic this_
```

I am now getting the error:

```
WARN   logExceptions, SQL Error: -5581, SQLState: 42581
ERROR  logExceptions, unexpected token: SELECT
```

If I remove `max({alias}.powerRestarts)` and replace it with either a constant or `max(s.powerRestarts)`, then the query works (but obviously does not calculate the rank correctly).

---

There seems to be a problem using the `{alias}` in this `sqlProjection` query - possibly something to do with the nested subqueries - can anyone help?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

HQL doesn't support subqueries in `select` list, thus you have two options:

- Write this query in SQL and execute it as a [native query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html)
- Write something like

  ```
  select max(stat.powerRestarts), stat.managedObjectName 
  from IPTStatistic stat 
  group by stat.managedObjectName
  order by max(stat.powerRestarts) desc
  ```

  then rank can be deduced programmatically from a row number

**UPDATE:**

An important point here is that you need to perform two aggregations (`max` and `count`) in order to calculate a rank, so that you need two queries to do it:

```
String sqlProjection = 
    "(select count(*) from " +
    "(select name from IPTStatistic s group by s.name " + 
    "    having max(s.powerRestarts) > max({alias}.powerRestarts)) " +
    "as r) as rank";
```

Also note the use of `having` instead of `where`, since condition should be applied after the first aggregation.

Comment: Thankyou, your answer is correct with regards to subselects being disallowed in HQL query select clauses (+1) but I realised I made a mistake in the question - the code is not actually HQL, it is an SQLProjection as part of a Criteria query, so is native SQL. I have clarified and corrected the question, see edits.

Comment: @KLibby: If so, how does the full criteria query look?

Comment: I have now added the complete code for the Hibernate Criteria that I construct.

Comment: @KLibby: Where is a `group by` in your criteria? It looks like you apply `max` without it.

Comment: I think it's nearly there but still have an error with the query - I have edited my question further to include the result of your solution and the SQL that Hibernate generates.